# Parse/map Angular 7 API response to model class

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular7, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I am new to Angular. Please excuse if anything is trivially missed by me.

I am trying to make an API call. For this I have created a base service class named base.service.ts (needed code below) -

```
public get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(BASE_URL + path, { params }).pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
}
```

I have also created a new service class named visitor.service.ts from where I call the base service's get method as below -

```
export class VisitorService {

  constructor(private baseService: BaseService) { }

    getVisitors(): Observable<Visitor[]> {
        return this.baseService.get(String.Format(Globals.endpoints.visitors));
    }
}
```

From my component class named dashboard.component.ts I load this visitors list -

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private visitorService: VisitorService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTodaysVisitors();
  }

  private loadTodaysVisitors() {

    this.visitorService.getVisitors().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data)
      }
    );
  }
}
```

My first question is - when I run this code, I do not see anything logged on the console. Why?

Also, my response will be in the following format -

```
[
    {
        "visitor": {
            "attendeeFirstName": "ABC",
            "attendeeSurname": "XYZ",
        },
        "visitorcheckin": [
            {
                "field": value,
                "field1": value1,
            },{
                "field": value,
                "field1": value1,
            }
        ],
        "visitorcheckout": [
            {
                "field": value,
                "field1": value1,
            },{
                "field": value,
                "field1": value1,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "visitor": {
            "attendeeFirstName": "DEF",
            "attendeeSurname": "PQR",
        },
        "visitorcheckin": [
            {
                "field": value,
                "field1": value1,
            },{
                "field": value,
                "field1": value1,
            }
        ],
        "visitorcheckout": [
            {
                "field": value,
                "field1": value1,
            },{
                "field": value,
                "field1": value1,
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I created a visitor model for this named visitor.model.ts -

```
import { Deserializable } from '../interfaces/deserializable.interface';
export class Visitor implements Deserializable {

    attendeeFirstName: string;
    attendeeSurname: string;

    deserialize(input: any): this {
        Object.assign(this, input);
        return this;
      }
}
```

The desrializable.interface.ts file -

```
export interface Deserializable {
    deserialize(input: any): this;
}
```

Is this the right way to create model for the above type of response structure? Also, how do I map response to my model objects and how can I use them in dashboard.component.ts?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to use [typestack/class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) library to map JSON with model classes. It is decorator-based and buys you much time.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid, i have corrected it and should be as follows,

> [
>     {
>       "visitor": {
>         "attendeeFirstName": "ABC",
>         "attendeeSurname": "XYZ"
>       },
>       "visitorcheckin": [
>         {
>           "field": "value",
>           "field1": "value"
>         },
>         {
>           "field": "value",
>           "field1": "value"
>         }
>       ],
>       "visitorcheckout": [
>         {
>           "field": "value",
>           "field1": "value"
>         },
>         {
>           "field": "value",
>           "field1": "value"
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "visitor": {
>         "attendeeFirstName": "DEF",
>         "attendeeSurname": "PQR"
>       },
>       "visitorcheckin": [
>         {
>           "field": "value",
>           "field1": "value"
>         },
>         {
>           "field": "value",
>           "field1": "value"
>         }
>       ],
>       "visitorcheckout": [
>         {
>           "field": "value",
>           "field1": "value"
>         },
>         {
>           "field": "value",
>           "field1": "value"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]

you could use [JSON2TS](http://json2ts.com/) to create the interface for your model and the resulting interfaces will be as follows,

```
declare module namespace {

    export interface Visitor {
        attendeeFirstName: string;
        attendeeSurname: string;
    }

    export interface Visitorcheckin {
        field: string;
        field1: string;
    }

    export interface Visitorcheckout {
        field: string;
        field1: string;
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        visitor: Visitor;
        visitorcheckin: Visitorcheckin[];
        visitorcheckout: Visitorcheckout[];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the JSON and the model piece. Can you please help me on how to parse my API response into the models as you mentioned?

Comment: there is nothing to parse, you could access using dot operator as its a json object

Comment: Its not logging in anything in console from the console.log(data) line in dashboard component. In the Visitor service class too, I modified getVisitors(): Observable<Visitor[]> { to getVisitors(): {

Comment: Okay, it is logging now as [object Object] [object Object]. I think I need to do some pipe(map stuff now, right?

Comment: try console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks. that did it.

Comment: But, now how do I save this stringified data in interface models that you mentioned?

Comment: You need to import the inteface and assign values accordingly., there are plenty of answers already